# I have a dictionary of lists, how to make a dictionary of the ith elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Working in python 3.

So I have a dictionary like this;

`{"stripes": [1,0,5,3], "legs": [4,4,2,3], "colour": ['red', 'grey', 'blue', 'green']}`

I know all the lists in the dictionary have the same length, but the may not contain the same type of element. Some of them may even be lists of lists.

I want to return a dictionary like this;

`$>>> Get_element(2)
{"stripes": 5, "legs": 2, "colour": 'blue'}`

I know that dictionary comprehension is a thing, but I'm a bit confused on how to use it. I'm not sure if it's the most elegant way to achieve my goal either, can I slice a dictionary?

Comment: You want the 2nd thing from each value? `{k: v[2] for k, v in d.items()}`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create `Get_element()` function this is the way to go:

```
def Get_element(d, i):
    return {k: v[i] for k, v in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
d = {"stripes": [1,0,5,3], "legs": [4,4,2,3], "colour": ['red', 'grey', 'blue', 'green']}

def get_element(d, i):
    return dict(zip(d, list(zip(*d.values()))[i]))

get_element(d, 2)

# {'colour': 'blue', 'legs': 2, 'stripes': 5}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def ith_element(d, i):
  return { k : v[i] for k, v in d.items() }
```

Here is a little dict comprehesion that will do the job. You just go over all key-value pairs in the dictionary one at a time and do some transformation with it resulting as another dictionary with the same amount of pairs as an exisiting one.

You can read more about list comprehensions [here](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-dictionary-comprehension).